# Software (gnome-package-kit) has disappeared from Gnome Shell Remix 12.10

Tags: gnome

Software (gnome-package-kit) has disappeared from my reinstalled Gnome Shell Remix 12.10

thankful for answers

Comment: how can i finde it and bring back?

Answer (score 2):

I recognized this at Ubuntu 12.10 Gnome Remix, too.

I reinstalled it now again via `sudo apt-get install gnome-packagekit` but it would be interesting why this happened.

Maybe because there is an update for the software manager coming?

Comment: Ask the developers of the distro, UGR is not and official derivative.

Answer (score 1):

After uppdate the program was gone,, however... last night i used terminal to install all my apps that I needed and i loved to do on this way..
For now, I don't need gnome-packagekit or software-center
I take a look on "https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/" finde what i want and
install i terminal.

thanks for the code and info.